# Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Tags: support, bug, new-users

Profile of the user https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/26545/surya-kanta-bose-chowdhury?tab=profile shows that user is a member for 4 days.

> Member for 4 days Last seen this week

But you can also see that the user has written an answer in April 2018. This answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26980.

How is this possible? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

If I remember correctly, the user "Surya Kanta Bose Chowdhury" contributed many posts but deleted his account later.

This is a new account with the same name and somehow one old post got linked to this incorrectly.

The history https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/26980/revisions shows that this answer was written by **user9969** and same userid is in comment response.

So, this seems a bug and that answer should not get linked to this new user account.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account says that "User deletion is irreversible!". So, old answers should not get linked to this user even if it's the same person.

Comment: I suspect the user is also the same (the old Surya Kant), But that can be confirmed only by the Mods.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer .. may be an explanation would have been useful here as to why it was downvoted